# apr_pool thread safety when using the apache runtime library

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, apr

Files and sockets in the APR API rely on pools, I see no way to create sockets/files without the use of `apr_pools`. Problem is that apr_pools are not thread-safe, thus creating a socket in one thread and destroying it in another is problematic.
How did you solve this problem in your multi threaded program?

I have already [asked this question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/apr-dev/201201.mbox/%3C20120127124337.12f30e4b%40mephisto%3E) on the apr mailing list, but there was no answer.

Comment: Strange library that does not supply threadsafe pools.  I would have thought that any cross-platform library would provide some link to an OS_specific synchro library that provides those primitives available on any OS, (mutex, semaphore), so that common thread-safe utilities like queues and pools could be built.

Comment: There is mutex support in apr.